Не загружается Windows 10
Надеюсь хотя бы на какую-то полезную информацию по проблеме.
Компьютер с Windows 10 при попытке загрузиться на экране с логотипом отключается (как будто даже подсветка) и уходит в ребут. Средство восстановления загрузки не помогает (srttrail говорит что все окей). Ошибка на BSOD сообщает о 0xc0000001. Разделы и конфиги загрузчика восстанавливал через template по конфигу. Пришел к выводу что базово загрузчик не сталкивается с проблемами и доходит до Kernel. Важное замечание: в безопасном режиме система прекрасно стартует. Бутлуп начался я так понимаю с обновления системы (возможно причина в драйверах). Куда копать дальше?

Если б это была Windows 11, можно было бы накатить наверх дистрибутив той же линейки с сохранением данных и программ. Это должен делать профи и почистить систему тоже потом должен обязательно профи. Как дела в 10 не знаю - операционную систему, снятую с сопровождения и готовящуюся умирать окончательно, не использую. Что я советую? Как можно быстрее нести в ремонт плюс приобрести переносной винчестер, на который Вам спасут Ваши данные. Это будет самое быстрое и надёжное решение.


Сделать резервную копию текущего состояния, при этом можно проверить есть ли место на диске.
На Windows 10 после двух неудачных попыток загрузки, происходит откат последних обновлений (не всегда)
Если грузится в безопасном, вручную откатить последние обновления.
Если все еще не работает, Нажмите правой кнопкой мыши по пункту Командная строка и выберите опцию Запустить от имени администратора. Введите команду DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth и дождитесь обновления DISM. Введите команду sfc /scannow и нажмите Enter. Следуйте инструкциям, чтобы проверить целостность файлов.
Если все еще не работает, проверьте свой диск чем-нибудь типа Victoria, если проверка проходит очень медленно или сыпятся ошибки, замните шлейф диска.
Проверьте память на всякий случай, чтобы не сомневаться.
Если все еще не работает, вспомните не установлен ли на компе КриптоПро, если установлен, удалите и повторите п.4.
Если все выше сказанное не помогло, восстановите систему из резервной копии, в противном случае переустановите или сбросьте к заводским настройкам.

